# how to use _mm_mask_add_ps instruction correctly?

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics, avx512

I wrote the test code as below. If I set mask 0b1111 or 0b0000, it works fine. If I use the mask combined with 01, 0b1101 0b1001..., the program crashed. A SIGILL signal which means illegal instruction is received in `_mm_mask_add_ps` when I debug.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
    __m128 vec0 =_mm_setr_ps(1,2,3,10);
    __m128 vec1 =_mm_setr_ps(4,5,6,10);
    __m128 src = _mm_setr_ps(14,15,16,110);
    __mmask8 mask = 0b1101;
    __m128 res = _mm_mask_add_ps(src, mask, vec0, vec1);

    alignas (16) float arr[4];
    _mm_store_ps(arr, res);

    float *p = arr;
    cout<<*p++<<endl;
    cout<<*p++<<endl;
    cout<<*p++<<endl;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
```

Comment: Get an AVX-512 CPU, or don't use AVX-512 instructions.  (With trivial masks, the compiler can optimize the intrinsic to the SSE or AVX1 form.)  Also, you probably don't want to leave `float arr[4]` uninitialized if you're doing conditional stores to it.

Comment: Or use SDE or another emulator to test AVX-512 code on a CPU without AVX-512.  If you actually just wanted to do masked `_ps` stores in general, look at AVX1 `_mm_maskstore_ps` (i.e. `vmaskmovps`), but note it's slow on AMD CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much bro for your explanation and associated link you provided.